# Is there a DomainDAO implementation that uses MongoDB for Authzforce?

Tags: authzforce

I'd like to use Authzforce with MongoDB as the PRP.

I saw that for the policy evaluation part there is already a MongoDB policy provider. Did someone try to implement the DomainDAO part for PAP support?
Are there other implementations besides FileBasedDomainDaoImpl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no DomainDAO implementation based on MongoDB for AuthzForce Server to my knowledge (as one of the main contributors), but you can use the MongoDB policy provider with [AuthzForce RESTful PDP](https://github.com/authzforce/restful-pdp) if you don't need all the features of AuthzForce Server. The RESTful PDP is a minimalist version but more customizable regarding the configuration of the PDP.